# Control window splitting while opening on files with helm

Tags: helm, window-splitting

I am trying to be able to control where a new window should go, when I use `helm-find-files`. I am aware of `split-height-threshold` and `split-width-threshold`, and it works if I set them to behave appropriately (`setq` outside the defuns). But what I am trying to do is set them temporarily before calling the function that actually splits the window (here, `helm-ff-run-switch-other-window`). However, even though these 2 variables have the correct values (using `let`), the functions don't seem to do anything. Perhaps the code will explain it better:

```
(defun my/helm-switch-other-window-horizontally ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((split-height-threshold 0)
        (split-width-threshold nil))
    (helm-ff-run-switch-other-window)))


(defun my/helm-switch-other-window-vertically ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((split-height-threshold nil)
        (split-width-threshold 0))
    (helm-ff-run-switch-other-window)))

(define-key helm-find-files-map (kbd "C-c s") 'my/helm-switch-other-window-horizontally)
(define-key helm-find-files-map (kbd "C-c v") 'my/helm-switch-other-window-vertically)
```

I guess I'm doing something wrong with variable binding?

Comment: You can let-bind around `helm-find-files-other-window` instead, it looks like `helm-ff-run-switch-other-window` itself doesn't call `split-window` etc at all in its life cycle. It is possible by using `run-at-time` etc, for example. Though I don't know the internal of helm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is based on your own code, which works as expected from here.

```
(defun my/helm-switch-other-window-horizontally ()
  (interactive)
  (with-helm-alive-p
    (helm-exit-and-execute-action
     (lambda (candidate)
       (let ((split-height-threshold 0)
             (split-width-threshold nil))
         (helm-find-files-other-window candidate))))))

(defun my/helm-switch-other-window-vertically ()
  (interactive)
  (with-helm-alive-p
    (helm-exit-and-execute-action
     (lambda (candidate)
       (let ((split-height-threshold nil)
             (split-width-threshold 0))
         (helm-find-files-other-window candidate))))))

(define-key helm-find-files-map (kbd "C-c s") 'my/helm-switch-other-window-horizontally)
(define-key helm-find-files-map (kbd "C-c v") 'my/helm-switch-other-window-vertically)
```

---

I don't have answer on why your let-binding don't work since I am not familiar with the internal of helm. Maybe the following may provide a clue:

```
(defvar x nil)
(defun foo ()
  (message "-> %s" x))

(let ((x 42))
  (foo))
;; Print "-> 42"

(let ((x 42))
  (run-at-time nil nil 'foo))
;; Print "-> nil"
```

as you can see let-binding `x` doesn't work for `run-at-time`.

Comment: Yes! I was going towards this direction following the other comments. My general question is: since `helm-ff-run-switch-other-window` calls `helm-find-files-other-window`, why using `let` like I did have the same effect? Does it bind only up to a specific level in the call stack?

Comment: @alexpeits I don't know, but at least let-binding doesn't work for `run-at-time`, I have updated my answer for this.

Answer (score 0):

The variables in let can not be accessed by functions outside.
`setq-local split-height-threshold nil` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Solution that worked for me in current version of helm, was overriding **helm-window-prefer-horizontal-split**

```
(defun my/helm-switch-other-window-horizontally ()
  (interactive)
  (with-helm-alive-p
    (helm-exit-and-execute-action
     (lambda (candidate)
       (let ((helm-window-prefer-horizontal-split nil))
         (helm-find-files-other-window candidate))))))

(defun my/helm-switch-other-window-vertically ()
  (interactive)
  (with-helm-alive-p
    (helm-exit-and-execute-action
     (lambda (candidate)
       (let ((helm-window-prefer-horizontal-split t))
         (helm-find-files-other-window candidate))))))

(define-key helm-find-files-map (kbd "C-c 2") 'my/helm-switch-other-window-horizontally)
(define-key helm-find-files-map (kbd "C-c 3") 'my/helm-switch-other-window-vertically)
```